# Encrypting URL inside PHP code

Tags: php, encryption, encoding

I'm trying to figure out the best method for encrypting or encoding a URL in my code, this is what it looks like:

`$ProUpdateChecker=new PluginUpdateChecker('http://the-url-is-here.com/file.json',__FILE__,'pluginslug');`

I want users to not be able to see that URL. I'm not too worried about them being able to decrypt it, I just want a little bit of added security since mostly newbies will be using my script anyways.

What is the best method to accomplish this? I used ionCube to encode the entire code (not just the URL), but it broke some of the functionality.

Comment: Did you considered url_encode and rawurlencode?

Comment: This is basically [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: It's not security at all, it's purely obscurity.  He said that.  "I'm not too worried about them being able to decrypt it."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt IDs in URL variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480908/encrypt-ids-in-url-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just store the base64 encoded version of the URL in your scripts as a string, and everywhere you use it run it through base64 decode.

```
$url = base64_decode('VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==');
```

Sort of a silly, poor man's option, but you said keep it away from noobs...

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to make it so the URL isn't readable ASCII text, try Base64 Encoding:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php