# Jersey encrypt URL

Tags: java, rest, url, encryption

I am using Jersey to implement REST web service.

This is my RESOURCE

```
@Path("/mywb")
public class FoodItems {
@Path("{ID}")
    public FoodItem getTodo(@PathParam("ID") String id) {
        return // my code.
    }
}
```

The URL to call that web service is :

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/myrest/mywb/1/delete
```

I want to encrypt the `id` parameter in the URL.

I have read about that and It seems that [UriBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) is the best practice to do that. but I don't know how to do it. any help would be appreciated.

**Also should I search for encrypt or encode ?**

Comment: What you mean encrypt? URL encode? `UriBuilder` is for that (encoding).

Comment: @acdcjunior I want the url to be secure, so should I say encrypt or encode ?

Comment: What do you mean by secure? What are you trying to avoid, here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt IDs in URL variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480908/encrypt-ids-in-url-variables)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the parameter in the request URL, you need to use something like Cipher, when the key is known to both client and server. Encrypt the parameter before sending and decrypt when you get it.

Another option is to send the parameter in the body, and then use https instead of http.