# encrypt url parametres send using xmlhttprequest

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, xmlhttprequest, parameter-passing

please i've been searching for a week now and i'm stuck .

I have a web app that send using xmlhttprequest in javascript to send value to be passed like a parametres in url like this :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1/filename/name.php?q="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

but if any one who get to know the url can change that value with any thing he want, I've allready implement the sql injection in the php files using : `real_escape_string`

but i need to crypt the value in the url , how can i do it ? i want to use ssl , but i didn't find aything on google , please dont give me a bad marks i really need answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt IDs in URL variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480908/encrypt-ids-in-url-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use POST. 
Look here how to do that:
http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sensitive and shouldn't be accessible to the user, you shouldn't be using JavaScript to handle it. JavaScript runs on the client and so is at its mercy.

There's nothing you can do to stop people requesting a URL, so the only thing you can do is not display the content when people inevitably do. Put some logic in `name.php` that figures out whether the person requesting the file has access to download it. If they don't, simply display an error.