# Encrypting URL for WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, url, encryption, devexpress

When using WCF Data Services, more specifically in DevExtreme's WCF Odata service in c#, is there any way of encrypting the URL queries? I do not want the client to be able to see/modify the URL in order to get access to the data. I want to know if this level of obscurity is available, even if have authentication for the client and that the client only has rights to one ID.

For example:

```
/AcountsByIntroducerID?entityID=1234
```

This URL exposes the ID and also allows a client to change the ID number. Would there be any way in WCF that would allow use to turn the above URL into a encrypted string?

Such as: `/JDudfj8ddJFDJSLAFDLJuaeouru0`

So this can be decrypted on the server side. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you check server-side if the client (that has hopefully authenticated to get to this system) has rights to the item at `entityID` and only show the data if they do? Security through obscurity is not a means to an end.

Comment: Yes you make a great point. I will keep that in mind, however I would still like to know if that obscurity is possible even in a scenario where the client must be authenticated and only has rights only to his/her id server-side.

Comment: @Jaiesh_bhai: But, this explains about encoding but not encrypting. They both are different, correct ? The OP has asked to encrypt. But, the above answer talks about encoding meaning still the data transmission is in-secure right ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt IDs in URL variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480908/encrypt-ids-in-url-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem to solve. For solve it i used the following pattern 
I have encoded url parameters in one base 64 string.

Declare your WCF with one parameter

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface VCIWCFService
{
     [OperationContract]
     [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{encodedParameters}")]
     string GetSomething();
}
```

In backend code you can decode encodedParameters with the following code

```
  string Url  = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedParameters);
  Url = Convert.FromBase64String(Url );
```

and you can get a particular parameter with HttpUtility class :

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(string.format("http://www.nothing.com?{0}",Url));
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("param1");
```

I work with Objective-C Ipad app, and i encode the parameters with the inverse system

Comment: Hi @tdelepine thanks for the response. If you don't mind, can you please elaborate a little more about how and where I would implement the UriTemplate on the client-side? Thanks

Comment: I edit my answer UriTemplate is in WCF déclaration Backend-side

Comment: @tdelepine But, this explains about `encoding` but not `encrypting`. They both are different, correct ? The `OP` has asked to `encrypt`. But, the above answer talks about `encoding` meaning still the data transmission is in-secure right ?