# How to encrypt Url in Servlet?Ho

Tags: java, servlets

I want to encrypt my Url in servlet .Please check my code below

**TestServlet**

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
      String url"Test2?name=bhanuprasd";
      response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
}
```

**Test2**

```
public class Test2 extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
        System.out.println("calling my first servlet");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        response.getWriter().print("hello"+name);
    }
}
```

when my request  redirect to my page in browser it's displayed name like this

```
**http://MyServer/Test/Test2?name=bhanuprasd**
```

I don't want to show the name in browser How can I do this. I try this way but not working

```
String url=java.net.URLEncoder.encode("Test2?name='bhanuprasd'");
String url1 =response.encodeRedirectUrl("Test2?name='bhanuprasd'");
```

Comment: May be you need to use `doPost()` method instead of `doGet()`

Comment: Thanks for the replay but when I am redirect the page How can i tell to server for post method by default it's go to GET method..Please help me

Comment: `doGet()` and `doPost` works almost alike. Just change the method name and I think you will be fine. See article [doPost() in doGet() in Java Servlets - What's the difference?](http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2012/10/dopost-in-doget-in-java-servlets.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt IDs in URL variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480908/encrypt-ids-in-url-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is POST instead of GET. Anyway you can encrypt your request params when adding them and decrypt before using them. I don't think there is a direct way of doing this.

PS: I think you are confused about usage of url encoding.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies you want to encrypt the parameters somehow, but then in the detail it doesn't seem that way.

If you don't want the parameters to be displayed, use a POST request as others have said. A POST request sends parameters in the body of the request, rather than in the query string. The Servlet container can handle either, via doGet and doPost.

If you want to use a GET request, but don't want the parameters to appear in plaintext, you can use an encoding like [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) and then URL encoding encode the parameters. Note that this merely obscures the text, and is not in any way a security measure.

If you want to encrypt communication between your server and the client, use [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

If you truly want to encrypt the parameters themselves, you'll likely need to do this yourself using public key encryption. There is no out of the box solution for this that I'm aware of, probably because it's not something applications need to do very often.