# ColdFusion Url Encryption Error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am working with some legacy code trying to replace the cfusion_encrypt and decrypt that was deprecated in ColdFusion 11.  I am receiving the following error:

> An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: The input and output encodings are not same..

I have been working with the answers found in the following thread:
[Hide/Encrypt URL variables in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207759/hide-encrypt-url-variables-in-coldfusion)

The encryption side seems to be working the way I would expected due to my URL ending in something like `.cfm?LS=%2A2%20J%2FNV16Q%25%5EWJ%40%20%20`

The decrypt side seems to be giving me problems and I am not sure what I am looking for.  Here is some of the code I am working with

This is how the encrypt is being set in the files and where the cfusion_encrypt was removed from.

```
 <a href="Menu.cfm?<cfoutput>LS=#URLEncodedFormat(Encrypt(LS, key))#</cfoutput>"
```

In my application.cfm file there is currently this code

```
  <cfif isDefined('url.LS')>
  <CFSET URLDecrypt(Key,LS)>
```

I tried replacing with this

```
<cfif isDefined('url.LS')>
<CFSET url.LS = #Decrypt("#Key#",url.LS)#>
```

and the code calls this function in a global file shared by all the applications.

```
 <cfscript>
 function urlDecrypt(key, LS){
 scope = "url";
 i = 0;
 thisPair = "";
 thisName = "";
 thisValue = "";

// Check for valid key
    if (not isDefined('LS'))
        LS = #cgi.Query_String#;

LS = cfusion_Decrypt(#LS#, key);   // Decrypt the Link string back into LS
//writeoutput(ls);  // for DEBUGGING

// set the variables
        for(i = 0; i lt listLen(LS, '&'); i = i + 1)
        {

            // Break up the list into seprate name=value pairs
            thisPair = listGetAt(LS, i + 1, '&');

            // Get the name
            thisName = listGetAt(thisPair, 1, '=');

            // Get the value
            thisValue = listGetAt(thisPair, 2, '=');

            // Set the name with the scope
            thisName = scope & '.' & thisName;

            // Set the variable
            setVariable(thisName, thisValue);
        }
    }
```

I know the function still has the deprecated cfusion_decrypt in it.  I am unsure how that should be replaced.

Comment: Look at the answer that @Leigh provided to this other similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22291776/1636917

Comment: As Miguel-F pointed out, the basic algorithm and an alternative to the deprecated function can be found on the linked thread. Ignore C# in the title. See [the answer by James Moberg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27240257/104223). That said the function is little more than obfuscation, so you should not rely on it - or the default cfmx_compat encrypt algorithm - for anything secure.